# man syscalls is missing in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, man, system-calls

I just can't find it. I've installed `linux-docs` with `sudo pacman -S linux-docs` but still `man syscalls` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `syscalls` man page is provided by the Arch Linux package `man-pages`. Install it with `pacman -S man-pages`.

Comment: I assumed that even in arch man-pages are installed automatically with the core packages since I have man pages for other commands

Answer (score 0):

syscalls manpage is available in [man-pages
package](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/any/man-pages):

```
pacman -Sy man-pages
```

Now it's installed:

```
$ man -w syscalls
/usr/share/man/man2/syscalls.2.gz
```

Notice that if you use official archlinux docker image you need to comment

```
# NoExtract  = usr/share/man/* usr/share/info/*
```

in /etc/pacman.conf before installing it (I'm not sure but I think
that regular Arch Linux comes with man pages already installed)